# Replace double quotes not surrounded by single quotes

Tags: regex, pcre

I want to replace double quotes with single quotes if they aren't surrounded by single qoutes using PCRE. Some examples, the meaning is input => output

```
"foo" => 'foo'
'foo' => 'foo'
abc "foo" => abc 'foo'
foo "bar", "baz" => foo 'bar', 'baz'
abc 'foo "bar" baz' => abc 'foo "bar" baz'
```

I tried `^([^'"]*)"([^'"]*)"` with the modifiers `m multi-line` and 'g global`. This works as far as there isn't more than one "xyz" block per line (fails in line 4).

EDIT: I forgot to mention that my current substitution is `$1'$2'`

Comment: Try [`'[^']*'(*SKIP)(*F)|"`](https://regex101.com/r/rR1mA2/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Great, thank you very much. This works like a charm

Comment: The solution will only work in case input strings have no escape sequences. Can there be escaped single quotes to be aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution below **will only work in case input strings have no escape sequences**:

```
/'[^']*'(*SKIP)(*F)|"/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rR1mA2/1)

- `'[^']*'` - match a single quote, 0+ chars other than a single quote and a single quote again
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - PCRE verb sequence discarding the match and proceeding from the current index (you can read more on that at [*How do `(*SKIP)` or `(*F)` work on regex?* SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex))
- `|` - or...
- `"` - a double quote.

**In case there are escape sequences, you need to write a parser.**