# Replace double quotes not surrounded by single quotes in Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Basically what I need is a regex expression that only selects double-quotes that are not surrounded by single-quotes. (This is in order to quickly refactor double-quote into single-quotes without breaking any nested strings).

Example (same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38638039/replace-double-quotes-not-surrounded-by-single-quotes)):

```
"foo" => 'foo'
'foo' => 'foo'
abc "foo" => abc 'foo'
foo "bar", "baz" => foo 'bar', 'baz'
abc 'foo "bar" baz' => abc 'foo "bar" baz'
```

So on searching for this question, I was able to find [how to do this in PCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38638039/replace-double-quotes-not-surrounded-by-single-quotes) but I wasn't able to figure out how to convert the `(*SKIP)(*F)` into usable Javascript Regex

My own Javascript attempt is:
`/(?:('.*["].*')|")/g` ([live demo](https://regex101.com/r/rR1mA2/3)).

The first pattern `/'.*["].*'/` goes a good job matching what I eventually want to exclude (`'foo "bar" baz'`) but I'm then unsure how to tell the expression that if this is matched, to exclude it.

I've tried playing around with the `(?!)` expression with no success.

If anyone has an idea on how to do either write a better regex or have an alternative solution to the problem I'd appreciate it.

EDIT:

As additional information, the regex expressions are being used for search and replace functions in WebStorm/PHPStorm to refactor source code.

Comment: This would be a heck of a lot easier when done with the mentioned `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` mechanism.

Comment: Yes it would! Unfortunately it's not valid regex in that program.

Comment: Can't you run a script over the code in question? This comes down to about fives lines, really. If this is not an option, have a look at http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html and scroll down to the `JS` section - but even this requires a full JavaScript functionality which `PHPStorm` might not have (not tested).

Comment: Jan, actually that's a good thought. Do you have a recommendation on that (software/script)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
"(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)
```

It will match any double quotes outside single quotes, [working sample](https://regex101.com/r/gU9tU3/1).

The trick is to search forward till the end of the line for a pair of single quotes, don't accept if odd number of single quotes is found.

Comment: This is really great, Koala -- and thanks for the explanation. Would this also be easy to expand to also exclude double-quotes that have single-quotes inside them as well?

Comment: Yes, the regex `"([^'\n]+)"(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)` but now it will match the whole text and capture the content, so you will need to replace with `'$1'`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the comment:

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
"foo"
'foo'
abc "foo"
foo "bar", "baz"
abc 'foo "bar" baz'
DATA;

$regex = "~
        '[^']*'(*SKIP)(*FAIL) # match everything between single quotes and fail 
        |                     # or
        \"([^\"]*)\"          # match double quotes
        ~x";

$data = preg_replace($regex, "'$1'", $data);

echo $data;
?>
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/JfUSRj).

Comment: Uh, the question asks for JavaScript, not PHP code?

Comment: @Bergi: Of course, you're right but read the comment section.

Comment: Thanks for putting this together Jan, I appreciate it.