# Replace outer single quotes (') to double (") and inner double (") to single qoutes (')

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've got something like this:

```
$class = 'class="cl"' . " style=" . '"color:black,' . "background:red;" . '"';
```

Is there any simple way by regex to format this code to `" ' ' "` style?
I mean this:

```
$class = "class='cl'" . " style=" . "'color:black," . "background:red;" . "'";
```

I tried this regex:

> `'(?!(([^"]"){2})[^"]*$)`

But this replaces outer single quotes `'` only. How can I also replace inner double quotes by single quotes?

Comment: I wonder it's solution if exist indeed. I think embedding condition is necessary here.

Comment: It is not possible without some code. What about a PythonScript script?

Comment: Wiktor, probably, yes. However maybe there is a regex solution with conditional replacement (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160927/how-to-use-conditionals-when-replacing-in-notepad-via-regex)). I found four step regex solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this in three steps, where only the first one needs a regular expression:

1. Replace each outer quote (whatever kind -- single or double) with a non-used character (e.g. `µ`), a pair at a time:

   **Find:** `('|")(((?!\1).)*).`
   **Repl:** `µ\2µ`
2. Replace each remaining double quote with a single quote, since by consequence of step 1 they are inner:

   **Find:** `"`
   **Repl:** `'`
3. Replace each occurrence of the special character (of step 1) with a double quote

   **Find:** `µ`
   **Repl:** `"`

Evidently the first (and only) regular expression does the major magic: it captures the first quote it finds (single or double) and then captures characters up to the next occurrence of the *same* kind of quote (using the `\1` back-reference in a negative condition and eventually matching that second occurrence with `.`). The condition for this to work is that all outer quotes come in pairs.

When you launch the first replacement, make sure that your caret is at the very start of the text so it starts outside of any quote pair.

NB: PHP (which you seem to use, but it's true also in several other languages) allows quotes with string literals to be escaped with backslashes. The task would become a bit more complex if such escapes were present in your input, but it is possible.

Comment: Hey Trincot, will this leave quotes when they dont need to change like in `" style="`

Comment: No, the first step will replace them, but the third step will restore them again. So in a way the answer is also "yes".

Comment: Oh yes you're right indeed, didn't pay attention enough to the answer :) Good answer btw

Comment: trincot, great! Thank you! :) I guess your solution is 100%. Now I'm testing with my files.

Comment: trincot, your elegant regex worked out all my source codes (20+ old files). No mistakes! :)

Comment: Good to hear! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

My own solution. There are 4 regex for Notepad++.

> **1.** Find all double-quotes (") inside two single-quotes (') and replace them with tilde (~):

```
RegEx: (?:\G(?!^)|([^']*(?:'[^'"]*'[^']*)*'))[^"']*\K"([^"']*+(?:'(?1)|$))?
Replacement: ~$2
```

> **2.** Find all single-quotes (') not surrounded by two double-quotes (") and replace them with backquote (`):

```
RegEx: '(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
Replacement: `
```

> **3.** Find all tildes (~) inside two backquotes (`) and replace them with single-quote ('):

```
RegEx: (?:\G(?!^)|([^`]*(?:`[^`~]*`[^`]*)*`))[^~`]*\K~([^~`]*+(?:`(?1)|$))?
Replacement: '$2
```

> **4.** And last step, all tildes (~) and backquotes (`) to replace with double-quotes ("):

```
RegEx: ~|`
Replacement: "
```

Tildes and backquotes should not be appeared in code before first step.
Thanks to [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39629715/3938424) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41001875/3938424)

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ uses the regex engine from the [Boost](https://www.boost.org/).Regex C++ lib.
So one can use [Conditional Replacement](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replaceconditional.html) in the replace string.

Using that trick then only 1 regex replacement can do the job.

In Notepad++

**Find what:**

```
(?:"[^"]*"\s*[.;]\K)|(?:(?:(')|("))(?=[^.;]*?[.;]))
```

About the regex, first it matches the parts surrounded by double quotes, and removes those from the match results via the `\K`.  The remaining quotes are then captured.

**Replace with:**

```
(?1")(?2')
```

**Search mode :**

```
Regular expression
```

**Example:**

This sample string:

```
$class = 'change="this"' . 'change="this" change="this"' . 'change"this"' . '"change:this,' . " keep=this" . " keep:this;" . "dontchange='this'" . '"' . '"change_me"';
```

Changes to:

```
$class = "change='this'" . "change='this' change='this'" . "change'this'" . "'change:this," . " keep=this" . " keep:this;" . "dontchange='this'" . "'" . "'change_me'";
```

Comment: LukStorms, thanks for your one step solution! :) ,but it does not work if there are more than 2 inner double-quotes. Try for example this: 'xxx="yyy"'
'xxx="yyy" xxx="yyy"'
'xxx="yyy"'

Comment: "xxx='yyy'" 'xxx="yyy" xxx="yyy"" "xxx="yyy"'      first string is ok, second one is not ok, third not ok also because of second string. But I agree and I think there is a solution with conditional replacement.

Comment: @newtonrus Urgh, multiple groups with double quotes between single quotes.  A pure regex replacement solution is kinda problematic with things like nesting and the like.  Anyway, I've changed my solution a tad. Now it'll also take care of those.

Comment: LukStorms, your new regex is more correct, but still there are mistakes. for example correct string like:  "dontchange='this'"          your regex is changing too: 'dontchange="this""

Comment: That's no longer changing in the current version.

Comment: LukStorms, I've tested your new version and found probably only one err: it does not change '"change_me"'  :)

Comment: @newtonrus Lol, this kinda reminds me of that esoteric programming language [Unreadable](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unreadable).  The previous version was looking for a dot after it. The new version looks for a `.` or a `;`